# How to force Nunit to release handles on native DLLs?

Tags: .net, nunit, pinvoke, nunit-2.5

I have code which require me to Pinvoke into a 3rd party native DLL. The issue is that when I use the Nunit test runner for those tests, the native dll is locked by the nunit processes (nunit.exe and nubit-agent.exe). Thus my post-build copy command fails because of this.

The only way to generate a 'successful build' (includes post-build command) is to first close Nunit, rebuild the project and re-open Nunit (Wash, rinse and repeat). This is becoming tedious and frustrating.

Is there any way to force unit to release all handles onto loaded assemblies? I have poked around the NUnit Settings a bit but to no avail.

**Side note:** The other thoughts I have had are along the lines of how I am actually using this 3rd party dll ( it's actually the C# SWIG version of QuantLib). So there actually may be issues with  the wrapper C# code and the IDisposable pattern used (based on a comment I received on another question).

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I am in the same situation.

Comment: @A.Murray - unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line option  from a tool like [unlocker to release all handles](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/). Or you could load the pinvoke functions into a separate app domain and then release the domain.

Edit:

In the second case. When create an AppDomain and then load the assembly that P/Invokes into that domain, but don't load that assembly into the primary App Domain. Then when the testing is finished unload the App Domain. [See here for an example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx)  Once the the domain is unloaded the P/Invoked Dlls should be released too.

Comment: Unlocker crashes Nunit every time. Can you perhaps expand on the second point?